# Magento How to get Active store name

Tags: magento

I need to know how to get the active Magento store name. I'm using this but with no result:

`Mage::app()->getStore()->getIsActive()->getName();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        /*It displays the current store name*/
        echo Mage::app()->getStore()->getName();
```

Comment: yes Thanks for the help but i need one more help if you could help me please. What i need is to display different category url on different stores. I explain you . What i am doing is , i have two stores diamond and stone. In diamond i am displaying direct product without category page so i did some modifications in navigation.php file that renders category Url but in stones i need to display the url that is displayed default in magento so i just need to check if store name is stone then default code generates the url & return $url but if it is diamond then it must execute my code. Thanks